# What is __FUNCT__ for?

Tags: c, conventions, c-preprocessor

I was looking at some [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/) example code, and I came across this snippet:

```
#undef __FUNCT__
#define __FUNCT__ "main"
```

right before `main` begins.

Is setting `__FUNCT__` or something like it before every function (or just main?) a standard C programming convention?

If so, why is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be shorthand or a work-around for a C compiler that doesn't support the `__FUNCTION__` standard macro.

Comment: What does the `__FUNCTION__` standard macro do? Does it just contain the name of the current function?

Comment: @Dan Yes, the `__FUNCTION__` macro is automatically set by the compiler to the name of the function in which the macro is invoked. It makes it very simple to write trace output and debugging statements.

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` is neither a macro nor is it standard - it can't be a macro as the preprocessor knows nothing about language semantics; C99 introduced a predefined identifier called `__func__` which does what hypercode described...

Comment: @Christoph Yes, technically you're correct. The mainstream compilers (VC++, GNU, etc) all call it a "macro" even though its a "magic" string constant. See the GNU docs: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Answer (score 5):

From [comments in the PETSc source code](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/snes/examples/tutorials/ex3.c.html) (`${PETSC_DIR}/src/snes/examples/tutorials/ex3.c`, lines 33-40):

> Note that immediately before each routine below,
>    we define the macro `__FUNCT__` to be a string containing the routine name.
>    If defined, this macro is used in the PETSc error handlers to provide a
>    complete traceback of routine names.  All PETSc library routines use this
>    macro, and users can optionally employ it as well in their application
>    codes.  Note that users can get a traceback of PETSc errors regardless of
>    whether they define `__FUNCT__` in application codes; this macro merely
>    provides the added traceback detail of the application routine names.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [petsc.h](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-2.3.2/include/petsc.h.html), there appear to be a bunch of macros which pass `__FUNCT__` as a parameter to a function, e.g.:

```
#define PetscFree(a)   ((a) ? ((*PetscTrFree)((a),__LINE__,__FUNCT__,__FILE__,__SDIR__) || ((a = 0),0)) : 0)
```

My guess is that `PetscTrFree()` (etc.) take these arguments for debugging/logging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

First all previous declaration of `__FUNCT__` are ignored by the compile using `#undef`, next the identifier is declared again and set to the string "main" in the line `#define __FUNCT__ "main"`

Personally I've never seen anyone do this setting it to "main", I can see it being useful if you want to use a library or something but don't want to use their declared function name of course I don't know why you would make this an identifier instead of just creating another function taking the same parameters and calling it what ever you want.

In any case, I do not believe this is a standar C programming convention and from the limited code snippet it is not clear exactly what it is being used for or why it is done.